# Issues with putting a php associative array into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to put an php associative array into Javascript. I believe the array is already JSON encoded because its being inserted into a mongodb, but I keep getting undefined as my elements to the Javascript array. If I use json_encode($Data) I don't get undefined in my javascript elements but each element is only one letter. 
ie: myArray[0] = {
myArray[1] = M
...etc..

PHP:

```
$Data = $_POST['data'];
$Data = json_encode($Data);
echo "<script>var myArray = $Data; </script>";
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    alert(myArray[i]);
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried to do it like this:

```
<script>
var myArray = new Array();
'<?php foreach($Data as $key => $val){ ?>'
   myArray.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
'<?php } ?>'
</script>
```

Please help!

Update: var_dump from php array

```
{ ["Manufacturer"]=> string(5) "Cisco" ["Device_Mdl"]=> string(27) "Cisco" 
["Mgmt_Subnets"]=> array(4) { ["Subnet_1"]=> string(7) "Subnet1" 
["Subnet_2"]=> string(6) "host 1" ["Subnet_3"]=> string(8) "Subnet 2" 
["Subnet_4"]=> string(6) "host 2" } ["Int_Info"]=> array(2) { ["Type"]=> 
string(6) "Inband" ["Vlan"]=> string(4) "4092" } ["VLANS"]=> array(2) { 
["Int_ID"]=> string(3) "tag" ["Int_Description"]=> string(10) "base" } 
["Version"]=> string(0) "" ["MGT_Address"]=> string(11) "103.56.78.6" }
```

Comment: Are you referencing your php code from a different file?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['data'])]` show?

Comment: _JavaScript_ doesn't have _associative arrays_, it just has _Objects_ and a special kind of _Object_ it calls _Array_

Comment: If you're seeing 1 letter at a time, it means `$_POST['data']` is a string, not an array.

Comment: the php is coming from another page. Updated code in question on the var_dump